# Reusing paste config entry

Tags: python, pyramid

I have the following Pyramid .ini file:

```
[DEFAULT]
redis.host = localhost
redis.port = 6379
redis.db = 0

[app:main]
...

# beaker session
session.type = redis
session.url = localhost:6379
```

In the `app:main` section's `session.url` I want to use what's defined under `DEFAULT` section's `redis.host` and `redis.port`.

In my understanding everything under `DEFAULT` section is global and is passed to other sections. But if I want to reuse a settings from `DEFAULT` and assign it a different name under other sections how do I do that?

I'm looking at the same way I can reference section entry in buildout .cfg files using `${<section name>:<entry>}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session.url = %(redis.host)s:%(redis.port)s`

Should do the trick.

Comment: Is there a syntax to do the same with variables that aren't in the [DEFAULT] section ?

Comment: There are no cross-section references other than between your section and default, or your section and an inherited section. This is all in the PasteDeploy documentation (the library that Pyramid uses to parse INI files).

Comment: I noticed though, even if I have `redis.host` under `DEFAULT` section which is supposed to be inherited by `app:main`, the `redis.host` settings together with other redis settings aren't present in Pyramid's settings under `main(global_config, **settings)` so I ended-up using different name under `DEFAULT` and use the actual `redis.*` settings under `app:main` instead.

Comment: They don't up up in `settings` unless they are actually set in the app's section. They are available in `global_conf` though. There is a difference between what's "available for inheritance" in the INI, and what shows up in the parsed output. BTW I'm not saying it makes sense. Just saying how PasteDeploy works. ;-)